# Systrace '/sys/kernel/debug/tracing/tracing_on' does not exist

Tags: android, systrace

I'm trying to use the [systrace tool](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/systrace-commandline.html) on the command line on my non-rooted Nexus 4 device running Lollipop 5.1.1. It appears that when I try to run commands such as:

```
systrace.py --time=4 -o testtrace.html sched app freq idle load
```

I get the following error:

```
CRITICAL:root:(TimeoutThread-1-for-Thread-1) Exception on ReadFile(01a599f5919448ea,
/sys/kernel/debug/tracing/tracing_on, retries=3, timeout=30),
attempt 1 of 4: AdbCommandFailedError("(device: 01a599f5919448ea) adb pull 
/sys/kernel/debug/tracing/tracing_on /var/folders/dj/xq_jq3wx6hg9gzw5r9svkmr00000gn/T/tmpGxH9ji/tmp_ReadFileWithPull: 
failed with exit status 1 and output:\n- adb: error: remote object '/sys/kernel/debug/tracing/tracing_on' does not exist\n",)
...
...
- adb: error: remote object '/sys/kernel/debug/tracing/tracing_on' does not exist
```

However, when I use the adb command:

```
adb shell /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/
```

I can confirm that the file 'tracing_on' exists.

Although, the systrace tool does work fine on the Android Device Monitor. The reason I want to use the command line is because I would like to programatically call the tool to analyse my application.

When I tried running the exact same command on other devices such as Oneplus 3 or Samsung Galaxy s6, the tool works perfectly and it is able to generate the html file. It is just on this device and Samsung galaxy s4 which generates the same error.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and restarted my adb session as root:

```
adb root
```

that did it for me.